# Get color output in bash

Tags: bash

when compiling some projects on linux terminal, I get usually a long output consisting of a lot of information. Usually this information is MONOCHROME. I wonder if bash can be modified somehow, so in all outputs or in some specific outputs (like from Makefile, etc) I can get different colors dependeing on, for instance:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory
```

or

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -I.
```

etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just use Bash functions, like, say this one:

```
make()
{
  pathpat="(/[^/]*)+:[0-9]+"
  ccred=$(echo -e "\033[0;31m")
  ccyellow=$(echo -e "\033[0;33m")
  ccend=$(echo -e "\033[0m")
  /usr/bin/make "$@" 2>&1 | sed -E -e "/[Ee]rror[: ]/ s%$pathpat%$ccred&$ccend%g" -e "/[Ww]arning[: ]/ s%$pathpat%$ccyellow&$ccend%g"
  return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
```

(Originally via [Highlight Warnings in Make](http://shawnwilsher.com/archives/184).)

Comment: The below answers are good and neat, but this is the only one that works in Solaris xterm

Answer (score 14):

I found that in bash `tput setf` doesn't work. I found this commands for bash that are working well

```
handy tput commands

tput bold - Bold effect
tput rev - Display inverse colors
tput sgr0 - Reset everything
tput setaf {CODE}- Set foreground color, see color {CODE} below
tput setab {CODE}- Set background color, see color {CODE} below
Colors {code} code for tput command

Color {code}    Color
0    Black
1    Red
2    Green
3    Yellow
4    Blue
5    Magenta
6    Cyan
7    White
```

Comment: `tput` is a great little tool with many [other commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983251/24874) for controlling the terminal state and contents in shell scripting.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this portably by using the `tput` command and the `terminfo(5)` database.
For example,

```
tput setf 5
```

with terminal as standard out, will set the foreground color to purple (or something like it; I'm color blind).  `tput setf 0` resets the foreground color to the default.

For more information, look up [`terminfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo).

Answer (score 1):

Installing and using [colormake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/colormake.1.html) is another simple option.

```
 sudo apt-get install colormake
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem more like you want the colorized output from make(1).
In that case, I'd recommend patches for gnu make from
http://git.goodpoint.de/?p=make.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/color-v5.1
described on the ML: http://old.nabble.com/-rfc--Colorized-output-for-GNU-make--td32547742.html